# How to write Prolog math functions

Tags: math, prolog

How would I write the following arithmetic expression in Prolog?

```
sqrt(9*log10(X)/5,9) * (1-(2X*sqrt(X)/5))^(2/7)
```

The square root is using the 9th root.

Comment: You should read some of the amply available documentation on arithmetic expressions/terms in Prolog. For example, [SWI Prolog arithmetic functions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%284,%274.26.2.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/arith.html%27%29%29).

Answer (score 4):

There is some variation between Prolog implementations, but I can promise you the following:

1. `2X` isn't going to work anywhere, except maybe a computer algebra system.
2. `sqrt` means square root. If you want to take the 9th root, you have to use a fractional exponent, such as `X ** (1/9)`.
3. ISO intends `^` for integer exponentiation and `**` for floating point exponentiation. Obviously, 2/7 is not an integer.

The expression you probably want is, therefore, this:

```
Y is (9 * log10(X) / 5) ** (1/9) * (1 - (2 * X * sqrt(X) / 5)) ** (2/7).
```

Notice my liberal use of whitespace. It's free, after all.

I get a lot of undefined errors for various inputs with this because you cannot take a negative number to a fractional power. I suspect this means one of us has a precedence error that can only be resolved by someone who knows what this formula is for and can compare to the original.

In the future, it would be a good idea augment your question with A) things you have tried, and B) what exactly your problem is. This question looks a lot like "do my work for me" which is probably why it's being downvoted.